# Where is the verse "ami sarvatmanayam atrapi srimad dasarathatmajah" found?

Tags: identification-request, brahmanda-purana

Rupa Goswami quotes this verse from Brahmanda purana in Laghu Bhagavatamrita:

tatha hi brahmande sri krsna vakyam

> *antaranga svarupa me matsya kurmadayas tv ami sarvatmanayam atrapi*
>   *srimad dasarathatmajah*

Where in Brahmanda Purana is this verse located ?